# How to set my logger to show debug messages?

Tags: java, logging

I'm sure this is easy, but I'm failing to find it.

I have a `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` instance for logging, and I see that the source code of one of my dependencies has statements like:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
    logger.debug("Doing stuff.");
```

I would like to enable debugging, so that I could see these messages. I'm using Maven to build, and run tests. I don't particularly care whether the solution is a command-line argument, adding something to `pom.xml`, or using code to set the logger itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `log4j.properties` specify `log4j.logger.com.yourpackage=debug`. If you don't have a `log4j.properties`, get a default one (google it) and place it on the root of your classpath.

(commons-logging will delegate to log4j)

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.logging.Log is not a logging framework. It is an abstract interface which helps you to have any concrete logging implementation under it.
                              There is a good chance that you are using log4j underneath the org.apache.commons.logging.Log api . If that is the case then place a log4j.properties at the root of your classpath. If you already have one then you just need to change the log level as specified in the file .
                               If you are using any other logger like jdk logger you need to find the logging configuration file for the same.